# Internal pdf viewer not working on Debian with TexLive for specific class

Tags: texstudio

I think this is new, because this is not the first time I've used Texstudio with `aa.cls`, but now when compiling this:

```
\documentclass{aa}

\title{We're great}
\abstract{We insist}
\author{a \and b}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}
        Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I'm using the latest class provided by Astronomy and Astrophysics ([aanda](http://aanda.org),  `aa.cls` which can be downloaded directly from [here](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/aa.cls)). The internal pdf viewer is just showing a rectangle where the header should be (in the proper place) and a small circle in the top right, presumably from the copyright symbol that's supposed to be there.

Here are the screenshots of the internal and external (Evince) viewers:
[image: internal] [image: external]

When compiling the internal viewer does mark where the text should appear, but you see the result below. I would rather stick with it as it's synced to the line I'm marking. oddly **commenting out** `%\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the `aa.cls` fixed this issue. I rather not do this, so what am I missing?

If relevant the specs are Debian 9, Tex Live package 2016.20170123-5. Changing the document class to `article` will remove this problem, and the viewer will work nicely as usual.

**Some testing**

Beyond the system package, I tried installing version 12 from the site, both qt4 and qt5, and version 11.2 (compiled from source). All show same behavior. I ran texstudio from the console to see if something is happening that I'm missing and I got a ton of:

```
Error (257): Missing or bad Type3 CharProc entry
```

This only happens for this document class (at least it doesn't happen for `article`). I found out this is thrown by the poppler library, but I don't know what would cause it. The result of `pdffonts` is:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       5  0
WCJTWI+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       7  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       8  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       9  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      10  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      11  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a virtual machine running Debian 9.

After installing also `cm-super` with Synaptic, here's a screen shot. In the terminal window you can see the output of `pdffonts` before and after this update.

[image]

Some more information: TeXStudio is version 2.11.2 (installed this morning; uses Qt version 5.7.1

```
enrico@debian:~$ apt list texlive
Listing... Done
texlive/stable,now 2016.20170123-5 all [installed]
enrico@debian:~$ apt list texstudio
Listing... Done
texstudio/stable,now 2.11.2+debian-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: For those looking for an apt command `sudo apt-get install cm-super`.